# Display All Woocommerce Products from all Categories on a Custom Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Ok so I'm having a really hard time with this, which I thought would be very simple but I can't seem to find ANYTHING on this topic.

I want to display ALL woocommerce products on a page that is not the shop page. I tried simulating this using recent products, but I realized that after a certain amount of time the products stopped showing up. Then I called the products by category, however after one category ended there would be a line break and the next would start, which would leave empty spaces in the grid. You can see how it is now [here](http://homa.krsites.com/todos).

I just want to display all the products, from most recently added to oldest. I don't want to display the categories, just the products, and I want it to be all on one page without pagination. I looked for a SHOP shortcode but Woocommerce doesn't offer one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can offset the `per_page` in the recent_posts shortcode parameter with `-1`

```
[recent_products per_page="-1"]
```

This will offset the value and spit out all the products. If you are embedding this into your template, sets the args as so:

```
$args = array(
          'per_page' => '-1',
          'orderby' => 'date',
          'order' => 'desc'
        );
```

Comment: thank you @ham-sandwich! My only doubt was whether there would come a time that a product would no longer be considered "recent" and would stop appearing, but i suppose it won't be a problem!

Comment: @Kelsey we don't thank each other on SO, we just accept answers by clicking on the tick. No, adding `-1` will prevent this :-) hope this helps.